# $Name not sent through HTML mail form

Tags: php, html, email

i found a good html mail webform online thanks to the people at CSS-tricks and everything seems to work fine. The form uses PHP as a module installed on Apache. In the form I ask for the user's name, emailaddress and a comment. Everything but the user's name arrives in my mailbox. I can't seem to find the reason why this doesn't work. This is my HTML-code:

```
    <div id="form_container">
        <form method="post" name="contact_form" action="contactengine.php">
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td class="description-column">
                <label class="description" for="Name">Name </label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <span><input id="Name" type="text" maxlength="455" value=""/ size="41></span>
            </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td class="description-column">
                <label class="description" for="Email">Email </label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <span><input id="Email" name="Email" type="text" maxlength="455" value=""/ size="41">
            </span>
            </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="description-column">
               <label class="description last" for="Message">Message </label>
             </td>
             <td>
             <span>
              <textarea id="Message" class="comment-box" name="Message" maxlength="455">                                    
              </textarea>
             </span>
            </td>
           </tr>

          <tr colspan="2">
           <td></td>
           <td class="buttons">
            <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
           </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
      </form>
    </div>
```

This is the PHP-code:

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "user@mail.com;"
$EmailTo = "info@mymailbox.com";
$Subject = "Mail";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

I assume that the PHP-code under //send mail would insert everything the user enters into the mail and send it to my mailbox. That means that it takes all data entered under $Body, which includes $Name. Yet it never sends me the name. 
I also wonder why in the first field "$EmailFrom" i should have to enter a fixed emailaddress (in this case 'user@mail.com') while the user enters his address in the html form and that gets sent within the mail i receive. The $EmailFrom field is just for me to see who has sent a mail without having to open the mail. It should also be the user's mail address or the user's name.

I hope i made myself clear enough?

Thanks in advance, i have already found lots of valuable answers on this site regarding other topics :)

B

Comment: `stripslashes`? Why? Are you stuck on an out of date server with Magic Quotes turned on, or do you just want to break user input?

Comment: Why are you redirecting people with `meta` instead of `Location` HTTP headers?

Comment: i found this form through a tutorial online dated 2007 so i assume some functionality might be deprecated. But just to be informed, can i delete the stripslashes and if so how would i do it?

Comment: Same for the redirecting, is it best practice to use Location?

Comment: Probably. Just remove the call to the function. Yes. Doing thing at the HTTP level is much more sane then sending an HTML document which does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Only form controls with `name` attributes can be successful. You don't have one.

```
<input id="Name" type="text" maxlength="455" value=""/ size="41>
```

should be

```
<input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" maxlength="455" value="" size="41">
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put name property in input tag

```
<td>
<span><input id="Name" type="text" maxlength="455" value="" size="41></span>
</td>
```

change to

```
<td>
<span><input id="Name" type="text" name="Name" maxlength="455" value="" size="41></span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to set `name="Name"` in addition to `id="Name"` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `name` attribute for your input tags,

`<input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" maxlength="455" value="" size="41>`